# Ionic deployment issues on android devices caused by minSdkVersion set to 10

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I've been trying to deploy an ionic app to my phone using `ionic run`.

The error message i get is the following.

```
    :processDebugManifestC: uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 10 cannot be smaller than 
version 14 declared in library
```

Every time i run, the setting minSdkVersion is set to 10 in the file AndroidManifest.xml. I have been unable to figure out the correct place to change this the setting for the minSdkVersion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

There is a preference setting in config.xml found at the root of an ionic project.

`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>`

The issue was solved for me by setting it to 14 or higher.